# Base64 for auth

Tags: base64, xmpp, zlib

I need to build a XMPP client. The server PLAIN mechanism to auth. (using zlib compression I think)

I captured trafic from other xmpp system thats use PLAIN mechanism and the text appear to be Base64 (id + token) `ADc1Y2M2OWY0MzQwMTUwMjgyOWIwMWY2MDAyN2E0NDE2ADE1YTk0NzM3NTRiYjY2MGExMGYzYTA5MzA5NWQxMmY3` is what the client return. I put that into a Base64 decoder and its give me this : `75cc69f43401502829b01f60027a441615a9473754bb660a10f3a093095d12f7`.

When I encode this using a Base64 encoder, Its give me something else than the first Base64 string (`NzVjYzY5ZjQzNDAxNTAyODI5YjAxZjYwMDI3YTQ0MTYxNWE5NDczNzU0YmI2NjBhMTBmM2EwOTMwOTVkMTJmNw`)

Can someone explain me? I couldn't find anything on google.

Edit:
https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0034.html#example-3

Comment: Do you use the same encoding format for the string ?

Comment: the result of your decoding is not correct, in fact the decoded value contains two binary values that can't be displayed as a character (here substituted by a �): `�75cc69f43401502829b01f60027a4416�15a9473754bb660a10f3a093095d12f7`. What you encoded then is based on a string in which the two binary values are not present, so you encoded basically something different and got of course a different result.

Comment: @jps its i used https://www.base64decode.org/ and its litterally token & accountId

Comment: Note that on the page you linked, it says: "For encoded binaries (like images, documents, etc.) use the file upload form a bit further down on this page." So do that. The top part of that page is for decoding to _text_. However your decoded data is _not_ text. It has bytes in it that cannot be represented in text.

Comment: Or better yet, don't use that page. Do your own decoding.

Comment: @JustinDupuis I also used base64decode.org and got a result with � in it. As Mark said, this is only for text. For such task it's usually better to write a few lines of code, e.g. NodeJS.

Comment: Oh okay. How can I use these binary values to encode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the result of your decoding is not correct, in fact the decoded value
> contains two binary values that can't be displayed as a character
> (here substituted by a �):
> `�75cc69f43401502829b01f60027a4416�15a9473754bb660a10f3a093095d12f7.`
> What you encoded then is based on a string in which the two binary
> values are not present, so you encoded basically something different
> and got of course a different result.

From [jps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7329832/jps)

Comment: I want to make this as anser